# How to make ffmpeg available inside my Docker container?

Tags: docker, ffmpeg, docker-compose

I'm currently trying to run a `ffmpeg` Docker image inside my own container with `docker-compose` using the `depends_on` clause. But when I try to reach `ffmpeg` inside my code, it seems like it's not available system-wide and I get an error. I believe I'm misconfiguring Docker.

My current `Dockerfile` is as follows:

```
FROM node:9

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install --quiet

COPY . .
```

And my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    command: npm run dev
    volumes:
    - .:/usr/app/
    - /usr/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - ffmpeg
  ffmpeg:
    image: jrottenberg/ffmpeg:3.3
```

When I run `docker-compose up` I can see that the `ffmpeg` is actually working, but then my application proceeds to start and it seems that `ffmpeg` ceases to work.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You are mixing two things `linking or depend_on` vs `multi-stage` image.

> Linking or depend_on is used for docker container network communication not to
>   access the application installed of the linked container.

when you link `DB` this means you can connect the database from your localhost  (3306 in container)

So what I will suggest installing FFmpeg in your nodejs container.

Here is Dockerfile based on `nodejs:alpine` which is more lightweight then `nodejs:9`

```
FROM node:alpine
RUN apk add  --no-cache ffmpeg
```

If you run the container or check in the container you will see its working fine.

[image]

**Update:**

You can pull the image from the Docker repository.

**Node verification**

```
docker run -it --rm adiii717/ffmpeg ash -c "node -v"
```

**ffmpeg verification**

```
docker run -it --rm adiii717/ffmpeg ash -c "ffmpeg -version"
```

[ffmpeg docker repository](https://hub.docker.com/r/adilm7177/ffmpeg)

Comment: Thank you, sir! Work like a charm.

Comment: glad to know. I will suggest alpine if youreally interested to work with docker

Comment: gives me the error as : WARNING: Ignoring http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz: Permission denied
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:

Comment: @Sarang just build it on my local system and its working fine. what is your base image? did you the above exact dockerfile?

Comment: yes using the exact same file, i guess maybe a network thing, is the docker image publicly available anywhere ?

Comment: yes @Sarang , you can pull from here `docker pull adilm7177/ffmpeg` also updating the answer. I check you other question too on weekend related to ffmpeg. I am sorry i think you have access issue. Just created for you :) keep the good work :)